# cakephp Column not found: 1054 user_id

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have made a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Now when I use bin\cake bake everything goes fine but when I go to the index view. I get an error `Column not found: 1054 Champ 'Users.user_id'`

This is the query that is made by Cakephp:

```
SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`, Users.username AS `Users__username`, Users.password AS `Users__password` FROM users Users WHERE Users.user_id = :c0 LIMIT 1
```

I don't know what I did wrong but the tutorial blog suggested to not use `user_id` but just `id` as primary key.

My model does have the displayField listed as user_id but it still doesn't work:

```
 $this->table('users');
 $this->displayField('user_id');
 $this->primaryKey('user_id');
```

Comment: take care case sensitive : `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS **users**  ` versus `SELECT Users.id AS **Users__id** `

Comment: Your alias has two underscores, `Users__id`, your `where` does not, `Users.user_id`. Also in cakephp you can use aliases in where clause?

Comment: @moskito-x Check the table alias.

Comment: @chris85 The aliased columns are used by the ORM, there's no need to use them in the `WHERE` clause, in fact you're actually supposed to not use them.

Comment: @ndm : `SELECT Users.id AS `Users__id`,..`

Comment: @moskito-x You were talking about case sensitivity of the table name, now you're pointing to something totally different, as alreay mentioned, the ORM uses these column aliases. using `Users.id` is absolutely correct, and won't cause any problem whatsoever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what I did wrong but the tutorial blog suggested to **not** use `user_id` but just `id` as primary key.

<sup>* emphasis mine</sup>

So then why *do* you use it? There is no `user_id` column in your table, so what you are seeing is the expected behavior.

The primary key is named `id`, so refer to that column instead of `user_id`. Also you don't want your display field to be the PK, using the username makes more sense.

```
$this->table('users');
$this->displayField('username');
$this->primaryKey('id');
```

Comment: i dont use anything it is cakephp that made all the syntaxis and keys i only made the tables. So that means cakephp does something wrong?

Comment: @user2157622 Possible, but pretty hard to tell without seeing the full picture, that is, all existing tables, the exact command that you're using, the exact CakePHP/Bake version in use, etc... usually when Cake uses unexpected column names, it is caused by cached schemas, ie changes were made to the table without clearing the cache (`tmp/cache/models`), but that's just _one_ possible cause.

Comment: Thank you very much it was indeed the cache that was the problem I deleted the files and rebaked everything and now it work perfect. I marked your answer above as the answer but it really is the cache that did the trick.